# How to Share functions in same controller in one view

Tags: laravel

Hi i have a Controller called homeController and a view called home.blade.php (home). I have 2 functions in my homeController that i want to use in my view 'home'.

The function called index() , works fine, but how do i get the values from function userchart() to my view 'home'.

```
public function index(){
$value1 = '';
$value2 = '';

return view('home', compact('$value1', 'value2'));
}

public function userchart(){

$value3 = '';
$value4 = '';

return view('home', compact('$value3', 'value4'));

}
```

Now in my VIEW i can only access $value1 and $value2

```
foreach($value1 as $key){
echo $key->value;
}
```

How do i get access to the data '$value3 and $value4'

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index(){
  $data['value1'] = 'value1';
  $data['value2'] = 'value2';

  $data = array_merge($data, $this->userchart());

  return view('home', $data);
}

public function userchart(){
  $data['value3'] = 'value3';
  $data['value4'] = 'value4';
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds :P